# mlflow cannot fetch model from model registry

Tags: amazon-ecs, mlflow

I have registered a model to mlflow model registry.

When I call ‘load_model’ function to try to fetch the model from model registry and try to make prediction, mlflow cannot find the model from the artifact path I provided:

```py
model_name = "sample-ann-1"
version = 1
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model("models:/{}/{}".format(model_name, version))
```

And return the following error:

```
"mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: The following failures occurred while downloading one or more artifacts from s3://{bucket}/5/8429aef5d8304990ae035c638db093e7/artifacts/../saved-model/model20/: {'': "ClientError('An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found')"}"
```

When I open s3 browser to check the file in artifact path (`s3://{bucket}/5/8429aef5d8304990ae035c638db093e7/artifacts/../saved-model/model20/`), I found the model is in the path, not sure why mlflow return *404 not found* error
[image: mlflow directory in s3 browser]

Answer (score 1):

There are **[multiple ways of creating model's uri](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.pyfunc.html#mlflow.pyfunc.load_model)**, including cloud paths (in your case: S3 bucket) or name/version pairs (your approach). Both ways work fine, for example on my Google Cloud I can do both:

```py
## load from bucket (here: Google Cloud)
model_uri = "gs://mlflow_experiments/test/3/467677aff0074955a4e75492085d52f9/artifacts/models"
mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_uri)

## load by name/version
model_uri = 'models:/toy-model/10'
mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_uri)
```

I would suggest to **confirm that the model is properly registered**, not only visible on Cloud. Test this (adapting appropriately):

```
client = MlflowClient(mlflow.get_tracking_uri()
client.get_model_version_download_uri('toy-model','10')
```

Answer (score 0):

The artifact you provided in `loaded_model` is not the artifact path you specified in S3. You should try this:

```
logged_model = "s3://{bucket}/5/8429aef5d8304990ae035c638db093e7/artifacts/../saved-model/model20/"

loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(logged_model)
```

Comment: `load_model` is designed to work with multiple model identifiers (see the link to docs in my answer). The pattern from the question works perfectly fine, the problem is somewhere else.